# How can I find a non duplicate value in a column, disregarding special characters?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have an attribute field of labels relevant to my work. I am looking for duplicates within this field; the issue is, the inputs are inconsistant.  For example:

```
Group  |  Label  |
---------------
1      |  H7     |
1      |  H-7    |
2      |  C9     |
2      |  C 9    |
3      |  D5     |
3      |  M 9    |
```

The result I am looking for is just:

```
3      |  D5     |
3      |  M 9    |
```

as these are truly different from each other.  I am using the following query currently:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE t3
WHERE t3.group IN (
  SELECT t1.group
  FROM TABLE t1, TABLE t2
  WHERE t1.group = t2.group
  AND (t1.label <> t2.label)
```

How can I get the query to disregard special characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `regexp_replace()`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM TABLE t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM TABLE tt
                  WHERE tt.group = t.group AND tt.rowid <> t.rowid AND
                        regexp_replace(tt.label, '[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '') = regexp_replace(t.label, '[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '')
                 );
```

This should return all the original rows that are singletons.  If you want all rows for a group where all are singletons:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM TABLE t
WHERE t.group IN (SELECT tt.group
                  FROM (SELECT tt.group, regexp_replace(tt.label, '[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '') as label_clean, COUNT(*) as cnt
                        FROM TABLE tt
                        GROUP BY tt.group, regexp_replace(tt.label, '[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '')
                       ) tt
                   GROUP BY tt.group
                   HAVING MAX(cnt) = 1
                  );
```

Answer (score 2):

If the "special" character can be anything other than alphanumeric chars, then you can use `regexp_replace`:

```
select max(t.group), max(t.label)
from your_table t
group by regexp_replace(t.label, '[^[:alnum:]]', '')
having count(*) = 1;
```

If there are only a limited number of special characters possible in the values, then perhaps a non-"regexp" solution would work - using `replace`.

Also, avoid using keywords such as "group" as identifiers.

Comment: beat me to it ;-)  I would throw in a space in the regexp_replace tho:  regexp_replace(label,'[^[:alnum:] ]','')

Comment: @tbone - No. Space is being considered as a special character. Eg. "C9" and "C 9" are to be considered same.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
select regexp_replace(label,'[^[:alnum:]]',''), count(1) cnt
from some_table
group by regexp_replace(label,'[^[:alnum:]]','')
having count(1) > 1
```

This will show the duplicate labels (based on alphanumerics only)